# Auth0 callback not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, owin, auth0

I have downloaded the seed project from Auth0 site for my ASP .NET MVC application using OWIN. However, when trying to log in using the google login in the widget the callback to /signin-auth0 throws an 404 exception. My understanding was that the callback to /signin-auth0 was supposed to be handled by the Auth0Account controller, but not of the code in the controller is being called during the login process. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: did you find the reason?

Comment: No, I have not yet.

Comment: Are you using the `app. UseAuth0Authentication()` extension to set up the OWIN middleware? This method takes an optional instance of type `Auth0AuthenticationOptions`, with a property `Callback` with a default value of `/signin-auth0` (that you can change). If you don't specify a different `Callback` then the OWIN middleware should be handling the `/sign-auth0` callback.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to add valid callback urls in the Auth0 dashboard, have you checked that?

If you follow the examples you do need to have a valid callback in your settings and in the dashboard in the Client settings, however your web application does not actually need to implement the endpoint unless you really need it (for instance if you want to use impersonation).
[This was my experience implementing 'database' users and Google logins via openId]

Comment: I have. They are all ok. I have found another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @noobie were you able to find the solution ?